# Fragment show/hide is not working at all

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been trying to build an android app for the purpose of understanding basic concepts behind fragments. But I am completely unable to show and hide fragment. 
Here is my code for onClickListner

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        PM_Fragment pm_fragment = new PM_Fragment();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);

        if (pm_fragment.isHidden()) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .show(pm_fragment)
                    .commit();

            b.setText("Hide");
        } else {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .hide(pm_fragment)
                    .commit();
            b.setText("Show");
        }
    }
});
```

Fragment is simply a text line in my case. And what the button is supposed to do is toggle the visibility of the fragment.
Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code?
And by not working, I mean that button does nothing when tapped, except for changing its text from "hide" to "show" and after that it keeps "show", no matter how many times you tap it. And this process has no effect on the behaviour of fragment at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't understand what you are trying to do here, but you never commit `ft` so your `Fragment` is never added to the `Activity`. I also don't understand the purpose of the two inner `FragmentTransaction`, but it is save to say that you **DO NOT** need them at all...

Define this globally:

```
private PM_Fragment pmFragment = new PM_Fragment();
```

And your `OnClickListener` should look like this:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);

        if(pmFragment.isAdded()) {
            ft.remove(pmFragment);
        } else {
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, pmFragment);
        }

        ft.commit();
    }
});
```

**IMPORTANT**: For `FragmentTransactions` to work, the `Fragment` has to have been added in code! If you add them in XML then they cannot be affected by `FragmentTransactions`! So if added your `Fragment` like this:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="at.example.fragments.SomeFragment" />
```

Or with some other similar method than I am sure that this is at least part of the problem. You need to add your `Fragment` solely in code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        SomeFragment fragment = SomeFragment.newInstance();

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentContainer, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Just replace the `<fragment />` tag with something like this in the layout:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/flFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

It will serve as a container for the `Fragment` you want to add. You can use the `FragmentTransaction` above to add the `Fragment` to this `FrameLayout`.

Comment: And from your existing answer, it seems to me that you are adding a fragment to the activity. But that part is working fine on my end. I need to toggle visibility on press of a button.

Comment: Helps you understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Seems kinda weird. And why don't you just add and remove the `Fragment`?

Comment: The button is just a trigger, you can generalize it with any other sort of trigger later on. and showing/hiding a fragment is quit a common scenario imo.  And in add/remove vs show/hide what are the trade offs?

Comment: No it's just weird that you are trying to hide a `Fragment`. You seem to treat it like a `Button` or some other control and want to make it invisible. And that's kinda weird, it's not that common to just hide a `Fragment` outright. `Fragments` are a modular container for a UI. That UI may be hidden or shown conditionally, but it is uncommon to apply that logic to a `Fragment`. Anyway I would always just add/remove it instead of showing or hiding it.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a solution to your problem.

Comment: How is it not working? It's working for me. You need to tell me what exactly is and is not working otherwise I can't pinpoint the problem.

Comment: How can I do that? There are no syntax errors. App is opening up fine on my nexus 5. I can see the fragment and button. Pressing button still does not do anything.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the `Fragment` is added, but you cannot remove it? Did you add the `Fragment` to the layout in XML or in code?

Comment: Yes I just confirmed it again, the code I posted above is working perfectly. I suspect you added the `Fragment` to the layout in XML, didn't you? Because `Fragments` which are added in XML, cannot be affected by `FragmentTransactions`. They cannot be removed or anything else.

Comment: Yes. But fragment is added before any press of the button. I have an xml file "pm_fragment.xml" in which common declarations and textView declared. And There is another "main_activity.xml" In which there is "fragment" tag, Which points to the "pm_fragment.xml"

Comment: Yes this `<fragment />` tag is the problem. You should avoid adding `Fragments` in XML. You need to do it solely in code. I have updated my answer with additional information.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. Though I used a relativeLayout as a fragment container.

Comment: Doesn't really matter which you use, but `FrameLayout` is performance-wise even better than the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Best answer ever ! @XaverKapeller